# What could be said about the cardinality of $\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i$ if $I$ and all the $A_i$ have cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

The countable union of a countable set is countable. Does the same hold for sets with cardinality $|\mathbb R|$. More specifically, if $A_i$ are sets of the same cardinality as the real numbers, and $I$ is an index set also with cardinality $|\mathbb R|$, is $|\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i| = |\mathbb R|$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question can be reduced to the question "is it true there is a bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$?" The answer is yes.

Comment: Well, more accurately, a surjection. But then, that's all you really need.

Comment: I just see that for a countable index set $I$, but I asked the question for uncountable $I$. So, how to reduce the problem in that case?

Comment: For a countable index set, you can imagine the elemnets in the countable union as the m-th element of the n-th set. So each element can be represented as an ordered pair in $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$. Can you modify this example for the real case?

Comment: Yes, I see. This gives us that $|\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i| \le |\mathbb R^2|$

Answer (score 3):

The question can be cast into cardinal arithmetic. We can prove the following:

> If $X$ is an infinite set, then $|X|=|X^2|$.

Moreover, we can prove the following cardinal arithmetic theorem:

> $\left|\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i\right|\leq|I|\cdot\sup\{|A_i|\mid i\in I\}$.

With equality in the case that the union is a union of pairwise disjoint sets. If $I$ and all the $A_i$'s have the same cardinality, then we get that the union has the same cardinality as them as well.

These proofs are not entirely trivial and require the axiom of choice.

Comment: I don't think it requires choice in the case $X = \mathbb{R}$, does it? Just use Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein and the injection $[0,1]^2 \to [0,1]$ given by interleaving decimal expansions.

Comment: No, it does not. But the union parts does require choice because we need to choose the bijections.

Comment: Agreed. (To me, it remains one of the great magics that C-S-B is choice-free, though the proof is simple.)

Comment: Yeah, definitely one of the greater mysteries of life!